# python axes.ravel() IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, axes, index-error

I am trying to plot 2*2 images. with the code below.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax = axes.ravel()
ax[0, 0].imshow(im1px, cmap='gray')
ax[0, 1].imshow(im2px, cmap='gray')
ax[1, 0].imshow(im3px, cmap='gray')
ax[1, 1].imshow(im3px, cmap='gray')
```

And it throws error messages like this
'''

```
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    in 
      1 fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
      2 ax = axes.ravel()
----> 3 ax[0, 0].imshow(im1px, cmap='gray')
      4 ax[0, 1].imshow(im2px, cmap='gray')
      5 ax[1, 0].imshow(im3px, cmap='gray')

    IndexError: too many indices for array
```

'''
Please help to tell how to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `ravel` ?

You are getting the error because `ravel` flattens the `2x2`, and then you are using a 2d index.

```py
>>> fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
>>> axes.shape
(2, 2)
>>> axes.ravel().shape
(4,)
```

Instead just use

`axes[0,0]`, `axes[0,1]`... etc.